# How do i get pandas.replace to work only on specified column?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

As i understand the `df.replace` of pandas works on the whole data frame unless you specify the nested dictionary in `to_replace`. What if i use `list`?

Is there a way to specify `list` in `to_replace` and corresponding values in `value` and specify the column?

For example:

```
A        B         C  D
1828942  1832772   3  100.00
1018081  1015631  -3   52.00
1116502  1120308   2   60.02
  54514    50708  -2   59.11
```

I basically want to replace values only in column C. For example, replace `[2,3,-2,-3]` with `[1,1,-1,-1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select that column and assign to it:

```
In [2]: df['C'] = df['C'].replace([2, 3, -2, -3], [1, 1, -1, -1])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
         A        B  C       D
0  1828942  1832772  1  100.00
1  1018081  1015631 -1   52.00
2  1116502  1120308  1   60.02
3    54514    50708 -1   59.11

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```